# Removing infected files after scanning with Malwarebytes' Anti Malware

Tags: virus, malware, malware-removal, anti-malware

Is it ok to remove the infected files after i scan my computer using Malwarebytes' Anti Malware?

does it can't affect my files when i remove the selected infections?

Answer (score 1):

It will depends of the infected files... But, except for your personnal (important) files, it's better to reinstall some software, the OS or to fix some bad behaviour than keeping the virus...

Answer (score 1):

Normally it will tell you which file(s) have been affected and it allows you to send them to quarantine rather than deleting. With this feature you can try opening files you want to keep in a sandbox environment and extract the data you need.

Comment: To add to this. You could 'remove' a file that is infected that is core to some application which would technically render it useless. But I would personally rather do that then stay infected.

Comment: @MrS definitely. A reinstall is simple, better safe than sorry.